# Add exsiting query to report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, expression, builder

My report calculates the stock of inks in my stores. I built a SQL statement in VB.NET and got the correct results. How can I display these results in my Crystal Report? Or design a report such that same results will be retrieved?

I tried to use SQL Expression builder but failed.

Comment: are you using sql query to get your results??

Comment: yes in vb.Net I use sql statement but i need to use it crystal reports and get same data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you will link Data Tables to your report using **Database Expert**. Do the same in Database Expert, select the Database and you can see **Add Command**. Select that and click the **>** button. You will get a Window, write your SQL Query there and press OK.

[image: Add Command]

After finishing this you can see **Command** in Database Fields which contains all your records got from the SQL Query as result.

Comment: this is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank Mr. Hariharan

Answer (score 2):

In `Database Manager` choose `Add Command` and then type your SQL Statement there.

Comment: while I'm preparing my answer you have posted the same, shall I remove mine?

Comment: yeah, thx for understanding !! and if i mention your name it got trimmed. why so ?

Comment: Sorry Mr. Hariharan I do not know why that is happening! I got the answer from you. Thanks

Comment: Thats fine ! Mr.Emanuele answered your question before me... I'm happy that you got the answer.