# Crystal reports: Can I have my own query

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

This is probably silly but I need to get this question out of the way. I am new in Crystal Reports, thus the ignorance. I would like to know if somehow is possible to select the database in the crystal reports with all of the tables etc. and then instead of selecting tables from the Database Expert, to write somewhere your own query. I am thinking something like the SQL Developer but in CR.

Comment: Checkout this link - http://www.hexcentral.com/articles/crystal-sql-commands.htm

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but nevertheless this is helpful regarding the commands!

Comment: This should be of some more help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812222/display-crystal-report-using-sql-statement

Comment: do you mean to select tables in database expert and write query as well? or just connect to db and write query?

Comment: @Siva Just connect to the db and write query.

Comment: Then you can use add command option as give in link of comment.. which is the way you write the query in crystal report

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your help!