# Ignore suppressed records in crosstab

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crosstab

My report shows only the *latest* diagnosis per patient based on their `date_of_diagnosis` - all other records are suppressed:

[image: Records after suppression]

I summarize by diagnosis and age group in a crosstab. Crosstabs evaluate before printing, so any attempts to suppress, share variables, or summarize happen *after* the crosstab populates. This means **Total in Each Age Group** is correct, because each patient only has one age - but if a patient has more than one diagnosis, even if they're suppressed, they get counted multiple times:

[image: Crosstab (Much larger in real life. Simplified/cropped for screenshot)]

I absolutely ***must*** use a crosstab for this due to the large number of diagnoses and age groups involved. How can I get the crosstab to ignore suppressed records? Or if I need to use a custom SQL Command table, how can I rewrite the existing SQL to ignore obsolete records?

---

Crystal's auto-generated SQL (through ODBC):

```
SELECT "Codes"."diagnosis_code",
       "Codes"."diagnosis_value",
       "Codes"."PATID",
       "Codes"."FACILITY",
       "Codes"."EPISODE_NUMBER",
       "Record"."date_of_diagnosis"

FROM   "SYSTEM"."Codes" "Codes",
       "SYSTEM"."Entry" "Entry",
       "SYSTEM"."Record" "Record"

WHERE  "Codes"."DiagnosisEntry"="Entry"."ID" AND
       "Codes"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Entry"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
       "Codes"."FACILITY"="Entry"."FACILITY" AND
       "Codes"."PATID"="Entry"."PATID" AND
       "Entry"."DiagnosisRecord"="Record"."ID" AND
       "Entry"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Record"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
       "Entry"."FACILITY"="Record"."FACILITY" AND
       "Entry"."PATID"="Record"."PATID"
```

Comment: Just saying: if you won't use the supressed data, then maybe you can add a condition to your query: `AND Date_Of_Diagnosis IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Just a note also: This not a practical way to join your tables, you should try to use LEFT or INNER JOIN

Comment: @Zeina (I know that. This is just the query that Crystal auto-generates. If I need to rewrite the query to solve this problem I'll use Joins.) The issue is not when the Diagnosis date is null, it's when the diagnosis date isn't the *latest* diagnosis per that patient. The crosstab ignores any suppression.

Comment: You should create a view in the database supressing all the old diagnosis of patiens, then use it as source of the report.

Comment: You can create your query in Crystal Report. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812222/display-crystal-report-using-sql-statement)

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals Ah, I had the wrong terminology. In that case my SQL *Views* were not accepted when I attempted to write them myself.

Comment: So, you cant create Views, but you can execute querys, in the example, they create a query as source of the report, not a view that will be saved in the database. In that case you dont have permission issues

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals Correct - I never meant to imply I couldn't write my own SQL query with Add Command, assuming I could get Crystal to accept it. I can't create *external* views.

Comment: Please provide your query to analysis

Comment: @Behnam You're lookin' at it. Any attempts to modify it beyond what was auto-generated have failed to pass Crystal's syntax checker. Nested selects, ordering by rownum, etc.

Comment: @4444, if you can't put a complex query that returns just the data you need in the Crystal Report itself, then put it into a stored procedure and call that procedure from CR. The main point is that this query should return only what you need, so that CR didn't have to suppress anything. CR should do only the pivoting/crosstab. If you explain the schema of your tables and provide some sample data with expected result, somebody would be able to write this query, it looks like standard `top-n-per-group` problem.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Could end-users use the stored procedure if I don't have write access to their system? I can only import/export reports, so I was trying to get a solution where the SQL is baked into the report.

Comment: @4444, sorry, I don't really know Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of Muffaddal Shakir's answer, I was able to write this query to perform the correct filter:

```
SELECT "Codes"."PATID",
       "Codes"."diagnosis_code",
       "Codes"."diagnosis_value",
       "Codes"."FACILITY",
       "Codes"."EPISODE_NUMBER",
       "Record"."date_of_diagnosis"

FROM "SYSTEM"."codes" "Codes",
     "SYSTEM"."entry" "Entry",
     "SYSTEM"."record" "Record"

WHERE "Codes"."DiagnosisEntry"="Entry"."ID" AND
      "Codes"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Entry"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
      "Codes"."FACILITY"="Entry"."FACILITY" AND
      "Codes"."PATID"="Entry"."PATID" AND
      "Entry"."DiagnosisRecord"="Record"."ID" AND
      "Entry"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Record"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
      "Entry"."FACILITY"="Record"."FACILITY" AND
      "Entry"."PATID"="Record"."PATID"

AND "Record"."date_of_diagnosis" = (   
    SELECT MAX("Record2"."date_of_diagnosis")

    FROM "SYSTEM"."entry" "Entry2",
         "SYSTEM"."record" "Record2"

    WHERE "Entry2"."DiagnosisRecord"="Record2"."ID" AND
          "Entry2"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Record2"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
          "Entry2"."FACILITY"="Record2"."FACILITY" AND
          "Entry2"."PATID"="Record2"."PATID" AND
          "Record"."PATID"="Record2"."PATID"
)
```

The key differences being:

1. The subquery uses unique aliases from the main query.
2. The last line `"Record"."PATID"="Record2"."PATID"` - Without this, the query only pulls back *one* diagnosis (the latest one in the whole system.) But now it   checks for the latest diagnosis *per person*.

Answer (score 1):

You need only the latest diagnosis among a set of diagnoses. So I would suggest:

```
SELECT "Codes"."PATID",
   "Codes"."diagnosis_code",
   "Codes"."diagnosis_value",
   "Codes"."FACILITY",
   "Codes"."EPISODE_NUMBER",
   "Record"."date_of_diagnosis"

FROM   "SYSTEM"."Codes" "Codes",
   "SYSTEM"."Entry" "Entry",
   "SYSTEM"."Record" "Record"

WHERE  "Codes"."DiagnosisEntry"="Entry"."ID" AND
   "Codes"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Entry"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
   "Codes"."FACILITY"="Entry"."FACILITY" AND
   "Codes"."PATID"="Entry"."PATID" AND
   "Entry"."DiagnosisRecord"="Record"."ID" AND
   "Entry"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="Record"."EPISODE_NUMBER" AND
   "Entry"."FACILITY"="Record"."FACILITY" AND
   "Entry"."PATID"="Record"."PATID"
   AND "Entry"."date_of_diagnosis" = (SELECT MAX("date_of_diagnosis") FROM      
   "DiagonsisRecord" "A" WHERE "A"."DiagnosisRecord"="Entry"."DiagnosisRecord"  )
```

This should get the maximum `Date_of_Diagnosis` for each patient and pass the filter parameter to get the last diagnosis of that patient.